# SVN options in STS - Existing Maven project

Tags: svn, maven, subclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm new to STS and SVN. In my workstation I'm having the SVN checked out source code (Maven Project) in a folder. And I have imported that maven project into SpringSource tool Suite (STS) using the option Import --> Maven --> Existing Maven Projects. 
After importing like this, I can work with the code, what I'm having as of now in my machine. But I cant use the SVN options in STS like update, commit and annotate. These features are not enabled for me.
I have installed Subclipse for SVN in my STS tool. 
Please guide me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about STS, but Eclipse, you could right-click on the project and select `Team -> Share...`

Answer (score 0):

If it is already in SVN then you want to use the SVN explorer to find the project and checkout from there. (Subclipse is a *decent* plugin for that)
Subclipse 1.6.x Update Site - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x
(you may want 1.7, 1.8 however)

Install the "M2E connector for subclipse" and you get an awesome new option called "Check out as Maven Project" which will pul out the project and all sub-modules as Maven projects in the STS workspace.  YOu will have full reversion history and can commit away.

Maven Integration for Eclipse Extras Update Site - http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras

Answer (score 0):

To install SVNKit as an Eclipse plugin or to make sure that you have the latest version installed, use http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.8.x/ as an update site location in Eclipse Update Manager.

```
In Eclipse menu select Help->Software Updates
Then choose 'Available Software' tab
Click 'Add Site...' button
Type http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.8.x/ in the 'Location' field and press 'OK'.
Check the new site (it should appear in the list of update sites) and follow further steps as prompted by Eclipse.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
or
```

In Eclipse, go to the Help menu → Install New Software...
Click Add... http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/
In Location copy the URL for the Subversive SVN Connectors
Click OK
Check Subversive SVN Connectors
Click Next, and then follow the instructions to complete installation